# After updating to OS 10 Swift 3 I am getting the following Web Filtering output message

Tags: webview, swift3, ios10

The App is working but wanted to know what this actually means?

```
WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2016-09-26 14:27:14.161509 Aviation USA & Canada[412:49541] 
WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this

Answer (score -1):

May be it is printing system log. Check that once and try this

1- From Xcode menu open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

2- On your Environment Variables set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable`
[image]